# how to add string to url before the last string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am want add string in between the url

I have an url

hostname.com/test1/test

I want to add test2 before the test

it should be hostname.com/test1/test2/test

Do I need break the strings with / and then again build the string by adding  tests?

Or is there any other way I can work on?

Comment: Using `split()`, and `join()`, would be the easiest way I can think of. Did you want to know how to do that, or are you simply looking for an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url ="hostname.com/test1/test";
var lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var output = url.substring(0,lastSlash) + "/test2" + url.substring(lastSlash, url.length);
console.log(output);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'hostname.com/test1/test';
var urlParts = url.split('/');
urlParts.splice(urlParts.length-1, 0, "test2");
alert(urlParts.join('/'));
```